# Sql statement conflict

Tags: php, mysql

SQL question

Having trouble with the following statement

```
select * 
from products 
where Shop = 3 
or Shop = 5 
or Shop = 6 
or Shop = 7 
and Active <> 0
```

It select's the shop/s no problem but total bypasses the Active part of the query??

I'm missing something but not sure what.
Have try moving the statement around i.e Active request first but may no difference.

Comment: Cracked it....select * 
from products 
where (Shop = 3 
or Shop = 5 
or Shop = 6 
or Shop = 7 )
and (Active <> 0)

Comment: better to use `Shop IN (3,5,6,7)`. It's shorter, easier to read and avoids OR chaining

Answer (score 2):

Do Like this

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE shop IN (3,5,6,7) AND active <> 0`
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE ( shop = 3 OR shop = 5 OR shop = 6 OR shop = 7) AND active <> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap OR statements in brackets:

```
select * 
from products 
where (Shop = 3 
or Shop = 5 
or Shop = 6 
or Shop = 7) 
and Active <> 0
```

otherwise Active <> 0 is evaluated with Shop = 7

Answer (score 1):

`AND` is evaluated before `OR`

```
SELECT * FROM products 
WHERE (Shop = 3 OR Shop = 5 OR Shop = 6 OR Shop = 7) 
AND Active <> 0
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM products 
WHERE Shop IN (3,5,6,7) 
AND Active <> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You should either use **IN** or **()**

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE shop IN (3,5,6,7) AND active <> 0
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE ( shop = 3 OR shop = 5 OR shop = 6 OR shop = 7) AND active <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like with brackets so SQL engine understands between your AND and OR conditions:

```
select * 
from products 
where (Shop = 3 
or Shop = 5 
or Shop = 6 
or Shop = 7 )
and Active <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The `and` priority is higher than `or`. So Shop = 7 and Active <> 0 are calculated together.
So the following statements are OK.

1. `SELECT * FROM products WHERE (Shop = 3 OR Shop = 5 OR Shop = 6 OR Shop = 7) AND Active <> 0`
2. `SELECT * FROM products WHERE Shop IN (3,5,6,7) AND Active <> 0`